# .NET Core Razor Class Library does not seem to work on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, razor-class-library

I have tried to create a .NET Core Razor Class Library.

```
dotnet new razorclasslib -o test
```

So far so good. But when I open it in VSCode, and create a new cshtml file and a new class to be the model for that, I get no suggestions for packages when I try to inherit the PageModel

Furthermore, in the csproj file, the target framework is set to netstandard2.0 changing it to netcoreapp3.1 seems to make no change whatsoever. I can't  find anything in the docs that gives me a hint as to how to deal with this.

Can anyone help me with this?

My system is elementary OS 5.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) and I'm using the dotnet 3.1 sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured it out. **Please note that real solution is provided after EDIT2. I have left the part in between as an example of what one should NOT do**

Omnisharp does did not tell me that I didn't have any of the packages with the required classes that i was referencing (doh!)

After some time spent in the documentation, i found the right ones, and here we go:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages --version 2.2.5
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc --version 2.2.0`

Adding those two packages fixed it all.

EDIT 2: Apparently I had overlooked a simple parameter that should be passed to the dotnet new command; e.g.:

```
dotnet new razorclasslib --support-pages-and-views
```

This is necessary to use MVC views and razor pages in a razor class library. Note that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages` should **NOT** be added as I did above.

Comment: Apparently, giving the `--support-pages-and-views` flag is adding a `<AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>` tag in the csproj file. Also there is no Mvc library reference as you mentioned.

Comment: Does this create blazor.server.js ?
I don't have it when using the publish and chosing linux.